# Flatten all subarrays in an array

Tags: python, numpy, flatten

I got a numpy array `X` which have shape `(2 , 2 , 3)` like this:

```py
X = [[[1 , 2 , 3 ] 
       [4 , 5 , 6]] , 
     
      [[7 , 8 , 9 ] 
       [10, 11, 12 ]],
```

I want to flatten all subarrays and turn X to the shape of (2 , 6) which is represented like this:

```py
X = [[ 1 , 2 , 3 , 4, 5 , 6 ] ,
     [ 7 , 8 , 9 , 10, 11 , 12 ] ]
```

But when I used `X.flatten()`, it just turned out to be like this:

```py
X = [ 1 , 2, 3, 4 , 5, ... , 12]
```

Is there any function to help me transform the array like what I mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterate over the array and flatten the sublists

```
arr = np.array([x.flatten() for x in X])
```

Or for numpy solution you can also use `np.hstack()`

```
arr = np.hstack(X)
```

Output

```
print(arr)
#[[ 1  2  3  4  5  6]
# [ 7  8  9 10 11 12]]
```

Comment: Yes I know it, but I'm asking for a module which can perform it immediately without having to iterate over all the subarrays please.

Answer (score 3):

Just `reshape`....

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([[[1 , 2 , 3 ],
       [4 , 5 , 6]],
       [[7 , 8 , 9 ],
       [10, 11, 12 ]]])


arr.reshape(2, 6)
```

result:

```
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6],
       [ 7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12]])
```

Answer (score 1):

Loop through the array and flatten the subcomponents:

```
x = np.array([[[1,2],[3,4]], [[5,6],[7,8]]])
y = np.array([i.flatten() for i in x])
print(x)
print(y)
```

---

```
[[[1 2]
  [3 4]]

 [[5 6]
  [7 8]]]

[[1 2 3 4]
 [5 6 7 8]]
```

Answer (score 1):

If its an numpy array you can use reshape

```
x.reshape(2,6)
```

Input:

```
x = np.array([[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]],[[7,8,9],[10,11,12]]]
x.reshape(2,6)
```

Output:

```
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6],
   [ 7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12]])
```